# Design help: Multiple User Roles

Tags: php, sql, authentication, permissions

I'm currently in the process of designing a web app that requires the use of user permissions and roles. The roles will be stored within the SQL database (using MS SQL but this should be a design independent of the implementation).

What is the standard practice for allowing a user to have multiple roles, a "One to Many" relationship if you will.

What I came up with conceptually is the idea of a int field that uses a bit flag to determine if the user has that role:

```
User Group | Permission Mask | Value
-------------------------------------
Basic      | 0 0 0 0 1       | 1
Advanced   | 0 0 0 1 0       | 2
...        |    ...          | ...
Admin      | 1 0 0 0 0       | 16
```

This way, on my PHP side's authentication I can quickly math out if a user belongs to the role or not. The biggest drawback I see with this is readability and understanding. For someone not involved with this design decision would they be able to figure out what's going on when maintenance/upgrades (new roles) come along?

**Is this appropriate for my needs? Is there a more standardized way of allowing users to have multiple roles/groups?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
User
------------
Id
Name


Roles
-----------
Id
Name


UserRoles - the UserID,RoleID combination has to be unique
-----------
UserId,
RoleId


Groups
------------
Id
GroupName


UserGroups - UserID, GroupID combination has to be unique
--------------
UserId
GroupId
```

Sample Data

```
UserRoles
----------------------------------------------
UserID  | RoleID
--------------------------
123       ADMIN
123       EDITOR
124       SITE-USER
```

### Queries

```
-- if no rows returned, then user does not belong to role
Select 1 From UserRoles Where UserID=123 AND RoleID='ADMIN'

-- get user roles
Select ur.ID, ur.Name From UserRoles ur
JOIN Role r ON ur.RoleID = r.RoleID
JOIN Users u ON ur.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE u.UserID = 123
```

Comment: So with the added complexity on the SQL side what kind of leg work am I expecting from a web development viewpoint? Looks like I'll be doing a lot more matching and boolean logic to determine roles or will I just need to be defining more complex queries?

Comment: That is normalizing your database - the queries are not complex

Comment: @codingbiz It in fact makes your queries easier! They will all be short one liners with this sort of structure.

Comment: Seems to be the consensus. I'll use this approach. Thanks for the detail and example.

Comment: that's what I meant in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something simple. It's a `*-*` relationship, why not implement it that way in the database? You would only need 2 more tables to map these roles to individual users, you could easily add new roles, and this would make sense for potential newcomers. Of course you would have to hardcode role access to functionalities initially, but you would have an easier upgrade path, would you want to have the whole thing configurable.